# Rewrite a function of $x+iy$ in terms of $z$ only

Tags: complex-analysis

How can you rewrite a function like

$$f(x+iy)=e^{2xy}\cos(x^2-y^2)-i\left[e^{2xy}\sin(x^2-y^2)+C\right]$$

in terms of just $z$? Are there any tricks that you can use or is it just the fact that you need to recognize the functions when you see them?

Comment: If you are allowed to use complex conjugation you can recover $x$ and $y$ from $z = x + iy$, using $x = (z + \overline{z})/2$ and $y = (z - \overline{z})/2$.

Comment: Hint: factorize $e^{2xy}$ in your expression and evaluate $-i\,(x+iy)^2$.

Comment: Hint: 1. Recognize $\cos(x^2-y^2)-i\sin(x^2-y^2)$ as $e^{-i(x^2-y^2)}$. 2. The exponent in the exponential becomes $2xy-i(x^2-y^2)$. Recognize $x^2-y^2+2ixy$ as $(x+iy)^2$. 3. Conclude.

Comment: @RobArthan Obviously $\bar z$ is off-perimeter here.

Comment: @Did: I have no idea what is off-perimeter unless the OP tells me.

Comment: @RobArthan Hint: `in terms of z only`.

Comment: @Did: Defining $f(x+iy):=$ some arbitrary expression in $x$ and $y$ does not a priori lead to a holomorphic function of $z$. You were unnecessarily unfriendly with Sam Cappleman-Lynes, who in the sequel deleted his answer.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Sorry, I fail to see your mathematical point. Re offtopic and misleading answers, what do you suggest? My choice is to signal them as offtopic as soon as possible (and to consider this as a service to the readers AND TO THE OP). Are you mentioning the deletion of this answer to regret it? If so, please explain.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have an expression for $f$ in terms of $z$. If we restrict $z$ to be real, then we are effectively replacing the complex variable $z$ by the expression $x + 0i$ where $x$ is a real variable. What we end up with  is an expression for $f$ along the real line in terms of $x$. What is miraculous is that we can reverse this process. That is, if we know an expression for $f$ when restricted to the real line in terms of the real variable $x$, we can recover an expression for $f$ on the complex plane in terms of the complex variable $z$. This follows from the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

For example, given $f(x + iy) = e^{2xy}\cos(x^2-y^2) - i[e^{2xy}\sin(x^2-y^2) + C]$, when we restrict to the real axis (i.e. set $y = 0$), we obtain $f(x) = \cos(x^2)-i\sin(x^2) - iC = e^{-ix^2} -iC$. How do we get an expression for $f(z)$? Replace $x$ by $z$. That is, once we know that $f$ restricted to the real line is given by $f(x) = e^{-ix^2} - iC$ we know that $f(z) = e^{-iz^2} - iC$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

---

As Rob Arthan points out below, in order to use the method above, you need to know in advance that $f$ is holomorphic (that is, the expression you are trying to obtain is in terms of $z$ only rather than $z$ and $\bar{z}$); you can check this by verifying the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations). The reason you need to know that $f$ is holomorphic in advance is the use of the Identity Theorem.

Comment: ↑ This is the view I think one should have. You were quicker than me, though...

Comment: How do you know the function is holomorphic? What if $f(x, y) = xy$?

Comment: The assumption that you can rewrite $f$ in terms of $z$ only (rather than $z$ and $\bar{z}$) is equivalent to holomorphicity.

Comment: But that isn't stated in the question. It is a valid procedure to guess that the function is holomorphic, calculate the restriction to the real line and then after replacing $x$ by $z$ check (somehow) that the result is equal to the original formula for all $z$.

Comment: @RobArthan: It seems to me that you interpreted "in terms of $z$ only" to include terms involving $\bar{z}$. I have never encountered this interpretation before. I have added a comment at the end of my post to clarify though.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the question whether "in terms of just $z$" was known to be possible or just hopeful thinking. But it's easy enough to check that the resulting function $f$ is correct in this case.

Comment: The exercise was to show that the function was analytic everywhere and then rewrite it in terms of just $z$. The expression at the top is the result i came up with and it is correct. Im going to try the approach you stated here, seems logic!